# Parse Issue: Expected Identifier ios

Tags: ios

I've been staring at my code for an hour trying to find this issue... I was wondering if I could get another set of eyes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_arrayOfHeaders count]; i++) {
    ((UITextField*)[mySingleton.arrayHeaders objectAtIndex:i]).text = [((UITextField*)[_arrayOfHeaders objectAtIndex:i]).text];
}
```

It is underlining the last square bracket in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of outer brackets in the RHS expression, then you are good to go:

```
((UITextField *)[_arrayOfHeaders objectAtIndex:i]).text;
```

Also, why are you making things harder for yourself as well as for others who are going to read your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _arrayOfHeaders.count; i++) {
    UITextField *textField1 = mySingleton.arrayHeaders[i];
    UITextField *textField2 = _arrayOfHeaders[i];

    textField1.text = textField2.text;
}
```

Comment: That did not fix it. I already tried that. Is there anyway to compile a clean build?

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting? It is probably somewhere different. For instance, where do you define `mySingleton`?

Comment: Right above the code I posted. The singleton declaration works fine because I've used it in other places. The code you just posted would not work the same as the code i wrote.

Comment: They are totally identical. Probably your code is doing something that we can't see from here. Are you sure you deleted square brackets `[]` not the parentheses `()`?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code into a notepad file, then recopied it into my xcode file and that has seemed to have worked. I have no idea why.